# How to select a random HTML element from the body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, random, getelementsbytagname

All I want is a way to select a random HTML element from the body (preferably with JavaScript or jQuery). It could range from the body itself, to a divide, to a paragraph that is embedded deep within several divides. I want to select this random element, and then be able to change its CSS style. This is particularly just for a fun easter egg for my website, but if anyone knows how to do this, that would be great.

Comment: what do you mean "select a random HTML element"? You will click it? Or you will click some button and some random element should become selected?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code does the following:

```
 var selectors = $('*:visible');
 selectors.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * selectors.length)).css("border", "1px solid red")
```

1. Selects all visible elements
2. Generates a random number less than
   selected elements
3. Selects based on the random number
4. Assigns a red border

Answer (score 3):

Something like this might work

```
// get all the elements from the body
var elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");

// specify a random index
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (0 - elems.length + 1)) + elems.length;

// get the random element
var randomElement = elems[index];

// do whatever
randomElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
```

Answer (score 0):

[randojs.com](https://randojs.com) can handle jQuery elements, so it makes grabbing a random element from the page super easy:

```
var jQueryElement = rando($("*")).value;
```

Then you can change the style however you want. For example:

```
jQueryElement.css({background:"red"});
```

Just toss this in the head tag of your HTML document, and you're ready to go.

```
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```